# The minimal polynomial of restricted T divides the minimal polynomial of T

Tags: minimal-polynomials, invariant-subspace

Given the linear operator $$T:V\to V,$$ $m(x)$ its characteristic polynomial  and $$W⊆V$$ invariant subspace, I want to prove that $$m_{T|W}\:\left(x\right)|m_T\:\left(x\right),$$ etc: the minimal polynomial of restricted T divides the minimal polynomial of T.

How can I show that ?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a question about minimal polynomials. But you say $m_T$ is the *characteristic* polynomial. Since that's inconsistent with various things, including standard notation, I'm going to assume you meant to say it's the minimal polynomial.

> > **Basic Fact:** Suppose $T$ is a linear operator with minimal polynomial $m$ and $p$ is a polynomial. Then $p(T)=0$ if and only if $m|p$.

Proof (this must be in the book, near the place where minimal polynomials are introduced): If $p=mq$ then $p(T)=m(T)q(T)=0q(T)=0$. Suppose on the other hand that $p(T)=0$. The division algorithm gives $$p=mq+r,$$where $q$ and $r$ are polynomials and $\deg(r)<\deg(m)$. Now $m(T)=0$ and $p(T)=0$ imply $r(T)=0$; hence the minimality of $m$ implies $r=0$, so $m|p$.

**So** it's enough to show that $$m_T(T|_W)=0,$$which is obvious: $$m_T(T|_W)=m_T(T)|_W=0|_W=0.$$

Comment: What is the proof of the "other hand" (second direction p(T) = 0), when the discussion is about characteristic polynomial ? 
You were right assuming I meant in this section the minimal polynomial, but the thing is that the "Basic Fact" is given as the previous proof, but not with the minimal polynomial, but with characteristic polynomial. I assume this fact is a special case of  a proof with characteristic polynomial, but I couldn't see the second direction proof.
Maybe by proof by contradiction ? 
Still didn't manage to finish it properly.

Comment: @Ilya.K.  It's not clear to me that the result in question is even true for the characteristic polynomial. In general the result corresponding to the Basic Fact is false. Say $m$ is the minimal polynomial and $C$ is the characteristic polynomial. Then $m(T)=0$ although in general $C\not|\,m$.

Comment: yeah, you're right about that, that a strange formulation I have in the instructions.

Comment: @david-c-ullrich I added for the question another part, I now how to prove it desolately from the question, but Im interested in a solution which will make major use of what was proven in the previous part. Do you have some ideas maybe ?